# How do I find and delete a cron job?

Tags: unix, cron

I created a cron job for a wordpress plugin that i no longer want running.  I am not very good at navigating around in unix.  The cron job was the following:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://ADDRESS_OF_THE_FILE >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Does anyone have pointers how to navigate to this cron job and delete it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should post this on Superuser.

Answer (score 13):

run in console:

```
crontab -e
```

then you will get crontab opened with an editor, simply delete the line there, save the file and quit editor - that's it...

Comment: Yep - this worked.  Turns out I was totally backwords with my whole set up and hadn't even saved the cronjob in the first place.  Sigh.  It's sad when something that should take 5 minutes takes an hour.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Run command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

It will open cron jobs in text editor. Remove your line and save the file :)

Comment: The sudo command didn't work for me, but removing it did.

Comment: @hollyb: `sudo` is needed just if you are running cronjob as root, but if you're running it as normal user - then you don't need it...

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing you certainly should be running everything as root.